# c# : Finding the RSSI of a Mobile Broadband connection?

Tags: c#, rssi

I am able to detect the RSSI of a WLAN connection using managed wifi.

My computer also has a Cellular Modem .

the Managed wifi class does not extend towards a Mobile Broadband Connection

Is there a similar class written for this that I could use .. ?